# How to extract text from previously inserted input with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

For some reasons, all I want is to get from the input field what I have just written IN THE INPUT FIELD just to check.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

xpath_user = '//*[@id="login-username"]'
user = 'user@yahoo.com'

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

chromedriver = dir_path + "/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get('https:\\www.yahoo.com')

driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_user).send_keys(user)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_user).text
print(element)

if element == 'user@yahoo.com':
    print("Good")
```

In this example, the output is '', but I want the actual 'user@yahoo.com', but I don't know if it is even possible because 'user@yahoo.com' doesn't appear in the html form of the page. Maybe I am missing something or there is a work around. I'll be glad if someone could help me. 
Note that my experience with python is limited.

Comment: are you sure there is an input for username on https:\\www.yahoo.com?

Comment: Yes, in this example I personally press fast the Authentication button.

Comment: Or we can use this link:
https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=fpctx&.intl=ro&.lang=ro-RO&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fro.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_user).get_attribute("value")`

The text property is for text within the tags of an element.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Note that it is 'get_attribute' :)